# MySQL Column Containing JSON string in Text Data Type to Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

I am new to Mongo but need to use it for a project at work.

I need to move some data into MongoDB from a MySQL server. I can import the column from the MySQL server into Mongo, but the data stays in column form because it is a string and a text data type. Is there a way to parse the JSON from the column after importing into Mongo? I would just use cold fusion and convert each cell to a file but there are millions of records. Just looking to see if there is a better way. Thanks for the help!

Here is an example of one cell in the column that was imported from MySQL. This is not complete, there is a lot more there. Also the JSON in each cell is valid:

```
{"cfid": 131146, "noun": "Cart", "value": 3, "cftoken": "b0ccc0c923077c03-D2ACF941-5056-A000-51C81C89B1058012", "cursign": "$", "currency": "US", "urltoken": "CFID=131146&CFTOKEN=b0ccc0c923077c03-D2ACF941-5056-A000-51C81C89B1058012", "cartvalue": 4, "isloginok": false, "itemavail": {"1": "In Stock", "2": "In Stock", "3": "will contact you"}, "sessionid": "MENU_131146_b0ccc0c923077c03-D2ACF941-5056-A000-51C81C89B1058012", "alert_list": "", "cartitems1": {"Custom": false, "PartNo": "224225", "Checked": false, "Quantity": 1, "extprice": 39, "subtotal": 39, "ArrayName": "Session.CartItems1", "FromSaved": false, "unitprice": 39}
```

Comment: I believe what you have is not a MongoDB issue, but the way you are setting up the data before saving it to the database. Can you share the lines of code where you prepare/save the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please format the data before insert  to the  database so that mongodb can be effectively identified.
if  it is  in String in or  a file  read it  and  use like  `Document.parse()` fuction  to  format it at  first .

you also  can  read  data form  mysql  put  it  to a map/JsonObject , then insert .

Comment: Is there any way you can elaborate on the second option? is the map/JsonObject done after the data is imported into mongo? And how can this be applied to all the cells in the field? I am just very confused sorry.

Comment: when  the data  in already  import  into  mongo  you  have to  foreach  documents  and  update  them  (_id  is  immutable )   to  new format  or  to  reload  them .